# Issues in using local::lib module usage

Tags: perl, cpan

I am trying to install all modules in my own lib location using [`local::lib`](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) module. But issue is all new cpan installations are going to the $HOME lib instead of the bootstrapped folder

These are my settings

1. cat .bashrc

   ```
   [ $SHLVL -eq 1 ] && eval "$(perl -I$HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 -Mlocal::lib=/usr/local/etc/zbxAdm/2.2/perl5)"
   ```
2. Used this command while installing Local lib

   ```
   perl Makefile.PL --bootstrap=/usr/local/etc/zbxAdm/2.2/perl5
   ```
3. sourced .bashrc file
4. When i try to install new modules using the below CPAN command, new installations are going to $HOME/perl5/lib/perl5 instead of the bootstrap folder

Do i need to modify the cpan settings? I have .cpan folder in my local user $home

Comment: are you using cpan, cpanplus or cpanm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your $PERL5LIB is set.

You should also try using "cpanm -l /usr/local/etc/zbxAdm/2.2/perl5 ".